# CSS3 logo animation?

Tags: css

I need to animate a logo, there is an example at this link (http://www.minmedia.nl/footer)

My problem is as follows:
Only the "Webdesign by" part and the two-colored pill part of the logo should be visible at the beginning of the animation. When you hover on it, the pill should move to the left, the "webdesign by" part should now fade out. Furthermore when the "pill" part of the logo is sliding to the left, the final part of the logo should become visible and slide as well to the left. So that the final display would be the full logo. 
When you move your mouse away again it should reverse and again the "webdesign by" text and the "pill" part of the logo should be visible.

I have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS but I don't have any experience with CSS3 animations/transitions.

If somebody could help me out that would be great, or if you would happen to know a link to a page that could help me out that be great as well.

Comment: You need to wrap all the components in a container and set the hover effect on that wrapper. Sliding items is best done by transitioning the transform:translateX() property. Fading should be done by changing opacity value

Comment: please include the markup here for us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a below sample of how you *could* use keyframes for this.

You **will** need to play around with the timing to suit your needs, as well as prefixing for `-moz-`, but the initial work is done for you. By using a wrapper, it is quite easy to set overflow hidden for your elements, although, strictly speaking, you could get away without, but again it depends on your situation.

I have also made an assumption that your image is 80px * 80px, but this can be adjusted.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap img {
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 80px);
  -webkit-animation: 3s picMove forwards;
  animation: 3s picMove forwards;
}
.wrap div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  top: 0;
}
.firstText {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 3s fade forwards;
  animation: 3s fade forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.secondText {
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: 3s movefade forwards;
  animation: 3s movefade forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes movefade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 80px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes movefade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 80px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes picMove {
  0% {
    left: calc(100% - 80px);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes picMove {
  0% {
    left: calc(100% - 80px);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="firstText">First</div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
  <div class="secondText">Second</div>
</div>
```